# How to get fragment in another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

My project consists of the following structure.

(Activity --> Fragments that can be attached)

```
MainActivity --> Fragment A / Fragment B

OtherActivity --> Fragment C / Fragment D
```

Both Fragment A and B can run OtherActivity, and I want to receive Fragments that will be attached when OtherActivity runs.

The most Naive approach is to send data to putExtra() when running OtherActivity on Framgent A and B, and to determine the Fragment to be executed according to the data.

Like this:

```
// FragmentA.kt
override fun onCreate() {
    binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), OtherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("frag", "FragmentC")
        requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
    }
}

// OtherActivity.kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    val fragment = intent.getStringExtra("frag")
    when(fragment) {
        "FragmentC" -> {
            setChangeFragment(FragmentC())
        }
        "FragmentD" -> { ... }
    }
}

private fun setChangeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

However, this way will increase the length of the code exponentially as the number of fragments to be executed in OtherActivity increases.

So, I tried to run it using findFragmentById.

```
// FragmentA.kt
override fun onCreate() {
    mViewDataBinding.btn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), OtherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("layoutId", R.layout.fragment_c)
        requireActivity.startActivity(intent)
    }
}

// OtherActivity.kt
private fun initFragment() {
    val fragmentLayoutId: Int = intent.getIntExtra("layoutId", 0)
    if (fragmentLayoutId == 0)
        finish()
    else {
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentLayoutId)!!
        setChangeFragment(fragment)
    }
}

private fun setChangeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

But it didn't work. This is because findFragmentById does not pass R.layout.somelayout in this way, but rather the id of the fragment tag or framelayout tag in the xml file of activity.

What would be the best way to do it in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches won't work.
It is not possible to share instances of Fragments outside of Activity. Moreover, you shouldn't do that in your app development. This is not how the Android ecosystem is designed.
If you want the same navigation to be applied to multiple screens I see the following ways to do that:

1. Use container Fragment with multiple fragments inside. This fragment will have logic related to proper navigation between fragments.
2. Use the same Navigation Graph for both Activities. - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started

Comment: Currently, the reason why activity is divided by two is because of the toolbar, so is it better to organize the toolbar for each fragment, leaving the activity as one? @Mike

Comment: I have worked with both approaches, and both have their pros and cons. I would say toolbar for each Fragment is easier to maintain. You can have a unified Toolbar which will be included in every Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I chose to reduce activity to one, and solved it by including Toolbar Layouts in the activity_main.xml and changing the visibility of the toolbar in addOnDestinationChangedListener in MainActivity.